# jquery, Any short version to change top position relatively

Tags: jquery

I want to add css top position relatively. 
if its top position is 30px, I want to add its position +30,
so its result is 60px.

so I have to do this like this,

```
$("#btn").css("top", $("#btn").css("top")+30);
```

is there any shorter way or effecient way to do this.

Comment: you can calculate it in a separate variable and can give the final value right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want you can use the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) method which allows increments, and use 0 as duration so that it occurs instantly.

```
$('#btn').animate({top:'+=10'},0);
```

example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/Pre8A/1/

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can always be shorter. Use a tool to compress or minify it, don't do it manually.

You can be more efficient by only getting your button once. Also, if you want others to see what you intend, it might be best to use self explaining variable names.

```
var btn = $("btn");
var top = btn.css("top");
btn.css("top", top + 30);
```

feel free to shorten this to

```
var btn = $("btn");
btn.css("top", btn.css("top") + 30);
```

P.S. The exact position of the element can be different than what you've specified in your CSS. If you experience positioning issues, look into jQuery function offset(), position(), etc -- see http://api.jquery.com/category/css/.

Comment: Also note what sarfraz says about integer/string. And note that parseInt needs a base 10 to make sure there is no accidental parsing from octal notation. Main point of my answer was to reduce the jQuery call to get the #btn element from 2 lookups to one. That's the main efficiency gain in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

another [way](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('#btn').css('top', function(index,value) {
  return value +30;
});
```

Comment: shouldn't you use the second param (value) of the callback function: function(index,value) { return value + 30; }

Answer (score 0):

That would add current top to 30 resulting in `30px30`, you should use `parseInt`:

```
$("#btn").css("top", (parseInt($("#btn").css("top")) + 30) + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$('#btn').css({top: +30});
```

It just adds 30 to the current value. Simple. This works for any other CSS value as well.

Comment: this is plain wrong. The +30 when given as a number means 30. But even if it was a string the `.css()` method does not support increments.

Comment: I have changed it so it's a dictionary, but it still should have worked before. From http://jqueryfordesigners.com, he uses `info.css({top: -90, left: -33, display: 'block'})`, and it works perfectly.

Comment: + and - in this case mean positive and negative .. not increment and decrement.

Comment: Look at the code in http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/. I'm sorry, but in this case you're wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery 1.6 you can use:

```
$("#btn").css("top", "+=30");
```